# Game Screeps - IDE Integration

Tags: javascript, screeps

I'm playing Screeps (http://screeps.com/) Simulation Room mode. I've been testing some scripts and I don't want to only save them to my local browser, I want to use an IDE to develop the code and push it to my github account. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to set up "sync from repository" under "GitHub Integration" in your Screeps "Account Settings".

Once this is done any IDE that pushes to that repository will be autmatically pulled into your account and executed.  This will affect the world and simulation scripts.

Comment: I'm using this method, myself. One thing to note is that if you make a tweak in the Screeps editor (when debugging new changes, or when your console is blowing up with errors and you don't want to take the time to open your IDE, change, commit, etc), those changes will be overwritten from your github repo the next time you sync. So make the same changes in your IDE that you make in the Screeps editor (if you only make the changes in the IDE, they'll sync to the Screeps editor, just not the other direction).

Answer (score 8):

So far there is no official way to integrate an IDE to Screeps. But this [reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/r/screeps/comments/2n7x8r/i_wrote_a_tool_which_adds_support_for_external/) has created a node.js script that can sync your local filesystem to your Screeps internal editor. If the IDE has git support, it's then possible to push the code to github.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible with grunt tasks. See http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/203022512-Commiting-local-scripts-using-Grunt

Comment: Nice, I haven't played in a while, will test this tonight. :)