# Possible to get line numbers or stack traces in Screeps?

Tags: javascript, screeps

In Screeps, is it possible to not just see the error in the console output, but also the module, line, and perhaps stack trace?

---

UPDATE: this is what the errors I get look like. I don't see a line number or stack trace, or perhaps a button to enable these?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9znxz5xe0j42616/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-06%20at%2012.21.18%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: It is not working for you? Please email us at contact@screeps.com what browser and OS you are using.

Comment: @artch I think the OP refers to error output and perhaps you are referring to the line numbers in the editor?

Comment: I am attaching an image of the errors I do see in the console. I'm using Firefox on OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: @Anima-t3d I refer to the line number and module names in error messages actually.

Comment: @tscizzle Could you try it in Chrome? I wonder if it works for your setup in Chrome.

Comment: @artch I tested myself: not working in FireFox, does work in Chrome. Just seems to be a browser issue and not OS related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time there is no full error support in console to do stacktraces in FireFox. Artch will have to implement it as a feature. Other browsers like Chrome and Opera seem to work. You can better transfer your localStorage to those browsers and work from there. However you can follow the [info in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27177457/3163075) and work from local filesystem and open in any browser if you have nodeJs installed.

Comment: Not quite true. In Chrome in most cases you should see correct stack traces like this one: http://i.imgur.com/6CYfiMA.png

Comment: @artch Thanks for the clarification. I'm using FireFox as well and never noticed stacktrace reports... Perhaps it's just my memory...

Comment: I used Firefox, they don't show up either. Recently introduced one of my friends to the game and he used Opera which DID show the error traces. It is near impossible to properly edit the scripts in Firefox as its pretty difficult to narrow down where the error originated. Make a backup of your localStorage and switch to Opera I'd say.

Comment: @Toolmaker I just updated my answer to take your comment into consideration. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/27177457/3163075

Comment: @Anima-t3d I saw that but couldn't get it to work under Windows/Firefox. Will try again under Opera tonight and see if I can use the node.js app to import my scripts into Opera.

Comment: @Toolmaker you need to have nodeJS installed. In firefox you need to paste the code the app gives you when you run it using `node sync` in your folder with the screeps js files. Perhaps open a new screeps question to get help?

Comment: I tried it using Node/Opera last night and the sync works but only when I reload. However, I see no point in using an external IDE if I don't get autocomplete and proper syntax highlighting for game constants. I tried Webstorm last night, including the library a reddit user made for highlighting, but its pretty useless since Game and related objects won't highlight. Too many squiggly lines.

Comment: @Toolmaker did you add the required code in the browser console, not the screeps console for the `sync` to connect with browser for livereload: `var s = document.createElement('script');s.src='http://localhost:9090/inject';document.body.appendChild(s);`

Comment: @Anima-t3d Yes I did. After pasting the thing into Opera Dragonfly's console the "Commit" button would always light up, as if there were changes to the code, but the code was only ever committed if I refreshed the page or used the back/forward buttons. Clicking the commit button didn't do anything either.

Comment: @Toolmaker If it was successful you should see your node console working and no need to use the in-game console panels. Try another browser and see if that works? I have it working in FireFox and Chrome (I don't have Opera).